# Selecting checkbox in a table from specific row and column using Capybara

Tags: xpath, capybara

I am new with Capybara and I need to select checkbox that is in the same column where is Wednesday. How can I select it? I tried several ways but I still get this error that element not found.

HTML part looks like this:

```
<table class="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 56px;">From</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 56px;">To</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Monday</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Tuesday</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Wednesday</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Thursday</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Friday</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Saturday</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Sunday</th>

                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 18px;"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr class="t-forminjector" id="rowInjector_1470ffb567f" style=
                "background-image: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" xmlns=
                    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <input name="t:formdata" type="hidden" value=
                        "H4sIAAIDOPgvsNqt">

                        <div class="timepicker"><input class=
                        "timepicker-input patternDailyStart hasDatepicker" id=
                        "patternDailyStart_1470ffb567f" name=
                        "patternDailyStart_1470ffb567f" type="text" value="">
                        <img alt="..." class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src=
                        "clock.png" title="..."></div><img alt="" class=
                        "t-error-icon" id="patternDailyStart_1470ffb567f_icon" src=
                        "spacer.gif" style="display: none;">
                    </td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" xmlns=
                    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <div class="dailyEnd">
                        <div class="timepicker"><input class=
                        "timepicker-input patternDailyEnd hasDatepicker" id=
                        "patternDailyEnd_1470ffb567f" name=
                        "patternDailyEnd_1470ffb567f" type="text" value="">
                        <img alt="..." class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src=
                        "clock.png" title="..."></div><img alt="" class=
                        "t-error-icon" id="patternDailyEnd_1470ffb567f_icon" src=
                        "spacer.gif" style="display: none;"></div>
                    </td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" xmlns=
                    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><input id="checkbox_1470ffb567f"
                    name="checkbox_1470ffb567f" type="checkbox"> <img alt="" class=
                    "t-error-icon" id="checkbox_1470ffb567f_icon" src=
                    "/mpromoter/assets/8fe900a87e3fabc9/core/spacer.gif" style=
                    "display: none;"></td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" xmlns=
                    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><input id=
                    "checkbox_0_1470ffb567f" name="checkbox_0_1470ffb567f" type=
                    "checkbox"> <img alt="" class="t-error-icon" id=
                    "checkbox_0_1470ffb567f_icon" src=
                    "/mpromoter/assets/8fe900a87e3fabc9/core/spacer.gif" style=
                    "display: none;"></td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" xmlns=
                    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><input id=
                    "checkbox_1_1470ffb567f" name="checkbox_1_1470ffb567f" type=
                    "checkbox"> <img alt="" class="t-error-icon" id=
                    "checkbox_1_1470ffb567f_icon" style="display: none;"></td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input id="checkbox_2_1470ffb567f"
                    name="checkbox_2_1470ffb567f" type="checkbox"> <img alt=""
                    class="t-error-icon" id="checkbox_2_1470ffb567f_icon" src=
                    "/mpromoter/assets/8fe900a87e3fabc9/core/spacer.gif" style=
                    "display: none;"></td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input id="checkbox_3_1470ffb567f"
                    name="checkbox_3_1470ffb567f" type="checkbox"> <img alt=""
                    class="t-error-icon" id="checkbox_3_1470ffb567f_icon" src=
                    "/mpromoter/assets/8fe900a87e3fabc9/core/spacer.gif" style=
                    "display: none;"></td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input id="checkbox_4_1470ffb567f"
                    name="checkbox_4_1470ffb567f" type="checkbox"> <img alt=""
                    class="t-error-icon" id="checkbox_4_1470ffb567f_icon" src=
                    "/mpromoter/assets/8fe900a87e3fabc9/core/spacer.gif" style=
                    "display: none;"></td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input id="checkbox_5_1470ffb567f"
                    name="checkbox_5_1470ffb567f" type="checkbox"> <img alt=""
                    class="t-error-icon" id="checkbox_5_1470ffb567f_icon" src=
                    "/mpromoter/assets/8fe900a87e3fabc9/core/spacer.gif" style=
                    "display: none;"></td>

                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" xmlns=
                    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <a href="#" id="removerowlink_1470ffb567f"><img alt="" src=
                        "/mpromoter/assets/8fe900a87e3fabc9/ctx/images/delete.ico"
                        title="Remove"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="t-forminjector" id="rowInjector">
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

When I copy the xpath then it looks like this: `//*[@id="checkbox_1_1470ffb567f"]`

That checkbox's id is every time different ( in the end those numbers change every time when I open the page.) But the checkbox_1 part is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contains()` function:

```
//*[contains(@id, "checkbox_1_")]
```